# Angular.io tutorial HeroService load no data from InMemoryDataService

Tags: angular, in-memory

I was following Angular tutorial to Step 7 [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

My `HeroService` return no heroes when calling `getHeroes()`. But I think it should return mock data defined in `in-memory-data.service.ts`. How should correct it?

I didn't find solutions,

- tried changing `heroesUrl` to `app/heroes`
- tried reinstall `angular-in-memory-web-api` by `npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save` (current installed version `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.0"`)

My code as follows:
**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 0,  name: 'Zero' },
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero } from './hero';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        console.log('in getheroes');
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
        return this.getHeroes().then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:
Issue resolved as suggested by @federico scamuzzi  in comment.
Change `.then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])` to `.then(response => response.json() as Hero[])` fixed it.

Comment: show your code ..

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Thanks for the quick response, sorry SO editor bother me a lot when I tried to upload my code as pictures, so changed as text format eventually. But code screenshoot still available here:  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMleS.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0HY0.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGN8l.png

Comment: Hi .. have you tried to don't use .data? ..so for example  .then(response => response.json() as Hero[]) or which version of Angular are you using? in the latest version the http provider is changed in Httpclient

Comment: Thank you @federicoscamuzzi it works! I am using the latest Angular 4. After using `response.json() as Hero[]`, I successfully saw the mock data. I was surprised the tutorial code is incorrect...

Comment: so if it helps you can you rate my response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to `don't use .data`? ..so for example :

`.then(response => response.json() as Hero[])`

P.S  --> Be Carefully of wihich version of Angular are you using... in the latest version the http provider is changed in Httpclient